# Java can't find libraries in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have Java maven project in Eclipse:

[image]

I have include required dependencies in pom.xml file and did refresh `alt+F5`. I `did maven build compile` without errors. But when I try to run file it looks like java can't load required classes from library:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    at main.TwoWaySerialComm.connect(TwoWaySerialComm.java:20)
    at main.TwoWaySerialComm.main(TwoWaySerialComm.java:107)
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Are you running this code on windows or unix machine?

Comment: I do code in windows machine and trying to run class from inside of Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy `rxtxSerial.dll` to %JAVA_HOME%/bin .Note:Not the `rxtxSerial64.dll`

Note:Download the right version ,`rxtxSerial.dll` has AMD and Intel two different versions.

Comment: You are right, it is related to `rxtxSerial.dll`. But I would like not change Java directory, but somehow connect lib to Maven project

Comment: Go to Project -> properties -> Java build path ->Find your .jar. Click on + to open the JAR's properties. Select Native library location and edit it to point to RXTX's shared library (.DLL, .so, .dylib).You can try this , I don't whether It works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your application with following JVM argument:

Linux: `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/librxtxSerial.so`

Windows: `java -Djava.library.path= "your dll path"`

JVM arguments are passed right after java command and before application main class or jar with main class.